# Silverlight.js file broken in IE9?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, internet-explorer-9

After downloading IE9, I found that running any Silverlight page breaks (only in IE9).

After clicking "yes" to debug, I was amused to see that the Silverlight.js file is choking on some JavaScript that was put in as a hack to work with previous versions of IE.

[image: IE9 Bombing]

What would the fastest way to fix this be?  Is there an updated Silverlight.js file I can download from somewhere?  Should I use a meta tag to tell IE to render as though it were version 7 or 8?

Thanks!

Comment: I had lots of problem with IE9 + Silverlight/JavaScript for my applications as well. The fastest way will be not to use ugly browsers from Microsoft :) or to fix all bugs for IE9 and to get more for other versions of IE :)

Comment: I never use IE - I'm just trying to get this to work for my users who do :)

Comment: Do you have to use silverlight.js? object tag works fine in Ie9 and the rest of the browsers.

Comment: I don't know, do I?  I'm not really a silverlight guru, but I assumed that file served some sort of useful purpose.  Does it really do nothing at all?

Comment: Interesting - it seems to work fine without it, like you said.  so what's the purpose of that file, anyway?

Comment: I've got a closely related question here, if you're interested in posting an answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808682/what-purpose-does-the-silverlight-js-file-serve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight.js is for helping your create object tags programmatically using javascript. It's useful when you don't want to load a silverlight object on page load. I use it in my projects and I don't see any errors with it. If you open up your silverlight.js file, it will have the version number on the first line. Mine says:

```
//v4.0.50401.0
```

What is your version?